# Robot Framework: Set Timeout in Robot framework

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I have created a framework in which I have used  `Set Browser Implicit Wait    30`
I have 50 suite that contains total of 700 test cases. A few of the test cases (200 TC's) has steps to find if Element present and element not present. My Objective is that I do not want to wait until 30 seconds to check if Element Present or Element not Present. I tried using `Wait Until Element Is Visible  ${locator} timeout=10`, expecting to wait only 10 seconds for the Element , but it wait for 30 seconds. 
Question : Can somebody help with the right approach to deal with such scenarios in my framework? If I agree to wait until 30 seconds, the time taken to complete such test case will be more. I am trying to save 20*200 secs currently Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to change the implicit wait right before checking that an element does not exist, and then changing it back afterwards. You can do this with the keyword [set selenium implicit wait](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Set%20Selenium%20Implicit%20Wait).

For example, your keyword might look something like this:

```
*** Keywords ***
verify element is not on page
    [Arguments]  ${locator}
    ${old_wait}=  Set selenium implicit wait  10
    run keyword and continue on failure
    ...  page should not contain element  ${locator}
    set selenium implicit wait  ${old_wait}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add timeout="${Time}" next to the keyword you want to execute (Exp., Wait Until Page Contains Element   ${locator}   timeout=50)

Answer (score -1):

The problem you're running into deals with issue of "**Implicit wait vs Explicit Wait**". Searching the internet will provide you with a lot of good explanations on why mixing is not recommended, but I think Jim Evans (Creator of IE Webdriver) explained it nicely in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164742/combining-implicit-wait-and-explicit-wait-together-results-in-unexpected-wait-ti#answer-15174978).

Improving the performance of your test run is typically done by utilizing one or both of these:

1. Shorten the duration of each individual test
2. Run test in parallel.

Shortening the duration of a test typically means being in complete control of the application under test resulting in the script *knowing* when the application has successfully loaded the moment it happens. This means having a a low or none Implicit wait and working exclusively with Fluent waits (waiting for a condition to occur). This will result in your tests running at the speed your application allows.

This may mean investing time understanding the application you test on a technical level. By using a [custom locator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45888950/centralizing-xpath-in-resource-file-how-to-pass-arguement-from-robot-file/45892958#45892958) you can still use all the regular SeleniumLibrary keywords and have a centralized waiting function.

Running tests in parallel starts with having tests that run standalone and have no dependencies on other tests. In Robot Framework this means having Test Suite Files that can run independently of each other. Most of us use [Pabot](https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot) to run our suites in parallel and merge the log file afterwards.

Running several browser application tests in parallel means running more than 1 browser at the same time. If you test in Chrome, this can be done on a single host - though it's not always recommended. When you run IE then you require multiple boxes/sessions. Then you start to require a [Selenium Grid](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/grid/) type solution to distribute the execution load across multiple machines.