# Error when passing command line arguments in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying this to pass the argument through command line

```
robot testingxpath.robot  --variable EXAMPLE:value

[ ERROR ] Parsing '--variable' failed: Data source does not exist.

Try --help for usage information.
```

Not sure what is wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Centralizing XPath in resource file, how to pass arguement from robot file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45888950/centralizing-xpath-in-resource-file-how-to-pass-arguement-from-robot-file)

Answer (score 3):

Try `robot --variable EXAMPLE:value testingxpath.robot`

[User guide (ch. 3.1.2)](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id595) says:

> When options are used, they must always be given between the runner
>   script and the data sources.