# Robot Framework: passing argument to a keyword that returns an XPath

Tags: selenium, xpath, robotframework

In my RF-Selenium project I have a language selection with a couple different options to choose from, which I locate through xpath. I usually separate my high-level keywords, locators/global variables and tests in 3 different files, so I need to get the xpath in one file and keywords in other.

The xpath that I tested and works when hardcoded looks like this: `//select[@id="language"]/option[@value="?hl=es"]` (and then change the 'es' to any other language identifier to locate other options). So, following the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40973598/how-to-use-variable-which-value-should-be-set-in-keyword-or-test-in-xpath/42732216#42732216) I built a "GET LOCATOR" keyword to take a language identifier as a parameter and return the correct xpath:

```
GET LOCATOR
  [Arguments]                         ${language}
  ${option locator}                   Replace String  ${LANG}  placeholder  ${language}
  [Return]                            ${option locator}
```

I have two different keywords that would use the return value from the GET LOCATOR keyword: in one of them I verify the currently selected language is disabled in the selection list:

```
  ${current}                          Get Element Attribute  html@lang
  Element Should Be Disabled          GET LOCATOR  ${current}
```

and then I actually select a different language and check the page has switched to it:

```
  Select From List By Value           ${LANGUAGE SWITCH}  es
  Wait Until Page Contains Element    GET LOCATOR  'es'
```

All of these is in the Resources file, while the ${LANGUAGE SWITCH} and ${LANG} variables are in a different file (and the Replace String keyword is in the String RF standard library).

The ${LANGUAGE SWITCH} variable holds a css selector that successfully locates the language dropdown. And I already did some tests without the GET LOCATOR keyword and they passed, like:

```
${current}                    Get Element Attribute  html@lang
Element Should Be Selected    xpath=//select[@id="language"]/option[@value="?hl=${current}"]
```

So I suspect there's a problem with my placeholder xpath, stored in the ${LANG} variable: `xpath = //select[@id="language-switch"]/option[@value="?hl=placeholder"]`

And this is the DOM part with the language selection dropdown:

```
<select id="language">
    <option value="?hl=ar">Arabic</option>
    <option value="?hl=zh-TW">Chinese (Traditional)</option>
    <option value="?hl=nl">Dutch - Nederlands‎</option>
    <option value="?hl=en" selected="" disabled="">English</option>
    <option value="?hl=el">Greek</option>
    <option value="?hl=es">Spanish‎</option>
</select>
```

To make things worse, the test using this keyword fails with no error message, as I only get:

```
| FAIL |
en
```

So... what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call a second keyword from `Element should be disabled` and `Wait Until Page Contains Element`. What is happening is that `Element should be disabled` thinks the locator is the string `GET LOCATOR` (which obviously doesn't exist), and the custom error message is `es`.

You will need to break that down into two steps:

```
${locator}=  GET LOCATOR  ${current}
Element should be disabled  ${locator}
```